# How to combine the two ajax functions into one? So, I can pass the two variables in the link at the same time

Tags: jquery, ajax

How to combine the provided two ajax functions into one? So, I can pass the two variables in the link at the same time. I am trying to pass the first name and last name through the http request to retrieve the record from the db using ajax functions. I am a newbie to ajax, please guide. Thanks.

code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showUser(str) {
  if (str == "") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
    return;
  } else {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
      }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET","test3.php?fname="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  }
}

function showUser1(str) {
  if (str == "") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
    return;
  } else {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
      }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET","test3.php?lname="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
    <div>
        <input name="fname" placeholder="Enter First Name" onChange="showUser(this.value)">
    </div>
 
    <div>
        <input name="lname" placeholder="Enter Last Name" type="text" onChange="showUser1(this.value)">
    </div>

</form>
<br>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here...</b></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script>
   //We need to pass the second variable in the function like this
    function showUser(fname,lname) {
      if (fname == "" || lname == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
      } else {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
          }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","test3.php?fname="+fname+"&lname="+lname,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
      }
    }
    
    
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>


   <form>
   //Add a new set of div tags which will consists of the two input fields. Then, add the onChange event in this div tag instead of input field tags. 
 
    <div onChange="showUser(fname.value,lname.value)">
        <div>
            <input name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="Enter First Name" >
        </div>
     
        <div>
            <input name="lname" id="lname" placeholder="Enter Last Name" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
    <br>
    <div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here...</b></div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```